# html include in edge browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, microsoft-edge

I've been trying to get a dynamic, client-side include play nicely in Edge browser and it doesn't seem to like jQuery based solutions around load().  Look at this plunkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/PwtpxpQlCVLbJOE7SKQc

```
<div id="b-placeholder"></div>

<script>
  $(function(){
    $("#b-placeholder").load("navigation.html");
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  navigation();
</script>
```

With an additional navigation.html defining my navbar and also the same done in the javascript function:

```
function navigation()
{
    document.write("<p> This is my other navigation</p>");
}
```

In Edge browser (and with other browsers) when viewing via Plunkr itself I see both navigation HTMLs included.  But when I copy this code locally only the javascript function renders.  From playing around with this (alerts in javascript) the jQuery is firing ok but the element is height 0.  Try as I might I can't persuade it to appear.  For the moment I'm using the javascript function solution but it's less clean and annoying as hell...

Comment: First of all, get rid of the [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write), it is primarily purposed to create new documents, not to add content to an exisiting document. Plunker might have overridden `write(ln)`  methods, and they're working, but you haven't done that in your local environment.

Comment: I'd say try `$(function(){
    $("#b-placeholder").load("navigation.html", navigation);
  });` and remove `navigation()` call